# How do I get an instance reference to the class that calls another method?

Tags: typescript

```
//TypeScript  I want make A a singleton pattern
class A {
    fun() {
        //How to get B instance when B call this function
        console.log("hello");
    }
}

class B {
    fun() {
        let a = new A();
        a.fun();
    }
}
```

How can I get a reference to the `B` instance in `A.fun()` when `B` calls the function?

Comment: class A{
 fun() {
  //How to get B instance when B call this function
  console.log("hello");
 }
}

class B{
 fun(){
  let a= new A();
  a.fun();
 }
}

Comment: pass `this` as a parameter?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [edit] your question to include more information. Please see the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Seems like a backwards inheritance issue. B _could_ extend A, but A still wouldn't be aware of B in this case. Hard to see what you're trying to do without context.

Comment: This sounds like an X Y problem. Use case please.

Comment: `class A {
    private caller;
    private static a;
    public static get instance():A{
        if(!this.a)
           // this.a=new A(); need a caller B //How to get B instance when B call this function
        return this.a;
    }
    constructor(caller){
        this.caller=caller;
    }
    fun(){

    }
    complete() {
        //some operation complete to call  B.complete
    }
}

class B {
    fun(){
        A.instance.fun();
    } 
    complete() {
       console.log("complete");
        
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `this` to `A.fun()`:

```
class A {
    fun(b) {
        // do something with the b instance
        console.log("hello");
    }
}

class B {
    fun() {
        let a = new A();
        new A().fun(this);
    }
}
```

All objects in JS are passed by reference, so you can modify `b` if needed.

Comment: I want no pass this to A.fun.Do you have other method?——typescript

Comment: I doubt you can do this with TypeScript. I don't think JavaScript's _reflection_ (or lack thereof) is clever enough to give you a traversable call chain that you can inspect to find whatever instance called `A().fun()`. Hence my previous comment on your question - is this an inheritance issue? - _Why do you want A to know that it was called by B?_

Comment: `class A {
    private caller;
    private static a;
    public static get instance():A{
        if(!this.a)
           // this.a=new A(); need a caller B //How to get B instance when B call this function
        return this.a;
    }
    constructor(caller){
        this.caller=caller;
    }
    fun(){

    }
    complete() {
        //some operation complete to call  B.complete
    }
}

class B {
    fun(){
        A.instance.fun();
    } 
    complete() {
       console.log("complete");
        
    }
}`